# How to format a phone number in python

Tags: python, string-formatting, phone-number

So, I've got a really poor implementation of a phone number formatter. It should take the instance value for a phone number format it and return it in format of xxx.xxx.xxxx (for now it should only be a US phone number)

The code can be found on this gist: https://gist.github.com/trtmn/a5a51c3da55ae0b32ac8

```
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
def formatphone(self): #Dear Future Self - I'm so very sorry.
    formattedphone = ""
    for x in self.phone:
        if x == "1":
            formattedphone = formattedphone + x
        if x == "2":
            formattedphone = formattedphone + x
        if x == "3":
            formattedphone = formattedphone + x
        if x == "4":
            formattedphone = formattedphone + x
        if x == "5":
            formattedphone = formattedphone + x
        if x == "6":
            formattedphone = formattedphone + x
        if x == "7":
            formattedphone = formattedphone + x
        if x == "8":
            formattedphone = formattedphone + x
        if x == "9":
            formattedphone = formattedphone + x
        if x == "0":
            formattedphone = formattedphone + x
    if len(formattedphone) == 11:
        formattedphone = formattedphone[1] + formattedphone[2] + formattedphone[3] + "." + formattedphone[4] + formattedphone[5] + formattedphone[6] + "." + formattedphone[7] + formattedphone[8] + formattedphone[9] + formattedphone[10]
    if len(formattedphone) == 10:
        formattedphone = formattedphone[0] + formattedphone[1] + formattedphone[2] + "." + formattedphone[3] + formattedphone[4] + formattedphone[5] + "." + formattedphone[6] + formattedphone[7] + formattedphone[8] + formattedphone[9]
    return formattedphone
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do it. A simpler version of your function would be:

```
def format_phone(self):
    # strip non-numeric characters
    phone = re.sub(r'\D', '', self.phone)
    # remove leading 1 (area codes never start with 1)
    phone = phone.lstrip('1')
    return '{}.{}.{}'.format(phone[0:3], phone[3:6], phone[6:])
```